# Is it possible to use Hibernate with EJB3?

Tags: java, hibernate, ejb

I can't find any example so I'm starting to doubt whether it is possible or not... But I was asked to build a webapp with both of them...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Its possible.. 
Please check the below link
http://www.techbits.de/2006/04/17/ejb3-persistence-with-hibernate

Comment: The link seems to be out of date, can you please update it - or provide a link to an equivalent resource? :)

Answer (score 6):

In short - yes, it's possible.

You can configure hibernate as a entity manager for EJB 3.0.

The configuration takes place in `persistence.xml` file. Here is a link to  [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/configuration.html)